# What is Berkeley's objections to Calculus?

Tags: math-history

What was Berkeley's objections that Maclaurin tried to answer?

[image]

Comment: This might be better suited for https://hsm.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Or, in what way does the Wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Analyst not answer your question?

Comment: I have looked at different resource, but I found nothing dealing with the response of Berkeley to Maclaurin. I guess that Berkeley was opposed to several concepts such as infinity and infinitesimals as well as velocity and how Calculus describes it. I also think that the concept of infinite sums leading to a specific quantity was (and may still be) problematic.

Comment: @kimchilover I see that the question has changed since you have posted your note. The reference does not address the question-image after the image became visible.